# USB connection issues

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, hardware-failure

I've been having USB connection issues for a while on my main computer, it started a couple of years ago on Windows and reamains now that I've switched to Ubuntu. I don't know if the problem comes from my motherboard, power supply or something else. It's really annoying and it always happens when I'm in the middle of something important and break my workflow...

Basically I get frequent disconnects of USB devices or moments where they aren't recognized as if they simply weren't there. This happens primarily with my keyboard on boot, where I have to wait or unplug it to be able to type my password and with my pen display tablet, that randomly disconnects making the pen unusable for a while. Sometimes I have to unplug it / turn is off and on again multiple times before it is recognized again, and sometimes even reboot.

I haven't had this problem with any of my devices on other Ubuntu computer I use, so I'm guessing it's a hardware problem on my main computer. Please if you have any knowledge that can help me find a solution regarding this kind of issue I would be greatful.

My computer's specs :

```
Motherboard : GIGABYTE Z97P-D3
CPU : Intel Core i7-4790K @ 4.00GHz
RAM : Ballistix Tactical DDR3 2 x 8 GB 1600 MHz CAS 8
Drive : Samsung EVO 850 250 GB
GPU : Nvdia GeForce GTX 1070
PSU : Corsair RM750i
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Do you have any device plugged into a hub, on a long cable, or with the cable running near devices producing RFI (e.g., cell phone)?

Comment: No, I do not use a hub, since my USB connectivity is already faulty, I didn't want to add more chaos. And no long cables or anything, just keyboard, mouse, usb microphone, webcam and pen tablet.